# How to use URL parameters and queries in Vue Router file

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, url-parameters

I want to use the URL params and Queries into the vue router defining file in order to set the title name dynamically.

I tried to use the `$route.params.paramName` format:

```
const routes = [
 {
    path: '/rooms/:room/:id?',
    name: `${$route.params.room}`,
    component: RoomsView,
    meta:{
      title: `${$route.params.room} ${$route.params.id} - WebsiteName`
    }
  }
]
```

Do you know how can I access these values?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best to let the component itself render the logic with something like

```
computed: {
 title() {
  const { name, id } = this.$route.params; 
  return `${name} ${id} - WebsiteName`;
 }
}
```

I think the [docs](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation) would give you some useful insight as well

Comment: I tried this and it didn't change the metadata title field (the title shown on the browser's tab)...

Comment: Can you post a little sandbox so I can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @sifislaz there is no way to set Title of the browser's tab through vue-router. Meta tags aren't for browsers, it's for navigation guards. You can change it through document object. Something like this: document.title = "New title".

Comment: Apparently you can access the parameters from the navigation guard and build there the reactive title of your document. Thanks a lot for your help.